# for each loop PHP, insert into SQL not inserting data

Tags: php, sql, database

```
$student_info = array(
                'student_number'=>$_POST['student_number'],
                'student_first_name'=>$_POST['student_first_name'],
                'student_middle_name'=>$_POST['student_middle_name'],
                'student_last_name'=>$_POST['student_last_name']);

foreach($student_info as $table_row=>$information){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO student_info_db (`$table_row`) VALUES(`$information`)";

    echo $table_row . " " . $information;
}
```

im not pretty sure why it doesnt insert any data on the database.
the echo $table_row $information are just to se if it gets the value and it succeed, but still doesnt insert any data. the question is, what was wrong ? im pretty sure im doing the correct sql .. or am i not ?

Comment: You are not running the query. Use mysqli_query($query) after your query string

Comment: All you're doing here is putting the query into a variable....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your sql query string is not correct. you are running query for each element!
it will insert data to each column for each time! you will have 4 entries for one student info in your table!

you also not ran query in the loop.

you should create query inside loop and then execute the query after the loop

You need to make query string first from your array.

First make your query like this:

try like this:

```
$student_info = array(
                'student_number'=>mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['student_number']),
                'student_first_name'=>mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['student_first_name']),
                'student_middle_name'=>mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['student_middle_name']),
                'student_last_name'=>mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['student_last_name']));

foreach($student_info as $table_row=>$information){
  $cols .= "`".$table_row."` ,";
  $vals .= "'".$information . "' ,";
  }
$cols = rtrim($cols,",");

$vals = rtrim($vals,",");

$sql = "INSERT INTO student_info_db (".$cols . ") VALUES(".$vals .")";
```

live Demo with sample data : https://eval.in/104428

then You need to run this `$sql` query

like this:

```
if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)
 echo "successfully inserted";
else 
 echo "something is wrong!";
```

Comment: @Bobski : did you try this?

Comment: gotta try this, sorry need to understand it more >_< im new in php, thanks.

Comment: -1, embedding unescaped input from `$_POST` into an SQL query is [a bad idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: @Ilmari Karonen:  is that okay now?

Comment: Yeah, although I'd prefer to do the escaping inside the `foreach`, at the point where you're generating the SQL.  If you always escape input at the last possible moment, and always assume that input is unescaped unless you've *just* escaped it, you'll never mistakenly think "oh, I already escaped that, no need to escape it again". It also makes it more likely that, if you ever copy the SQL-generating code, you'll copy the escaping code along with it.

Answer (score 2):

You did not execute your query! At first establish the connection with database. Then add mysql_query($sql) for executing the query.

```
$student_info = array(
            'student_number'=>mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['student_number'])),
            'student_first_name'=>mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['student_first_name'])),
            'student_middle_name'=>mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['student_middle_name'])),
            'student_last_name'=>mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['student_last_name'])));

//First we need to make a connection with the database
$host='localhost'; // Host Name.
$db_user= 'root'; //User Name
$db_password= 'nopass';
$db= 'product_record'; // Database Name.
$conn=mysql_connect($host,$db_user,$db_password) or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db) or die (mysql_error());

$column = "";
$value = ""; 
foreach($student_info as $table_row=>$information){
  if($column != ""){
    $column .= ",";
    $value .= ","; 
  }

  $column .= $table_row;
  $value .= "'".$information."'";

}

$sql = "INSERT INTO student_info_db (".$column.") VALUES(".$value.")";

mysql_query($sql);  
mysql_close($conn);
```

Comment: -1, embedding unescaped input from `$_POST` into an SQL query is [a bad idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: I edit my answer. Could you please check this out? :)

Comment: It looks OK now, although I'll [echo my earlier comment to Awlad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21949944/for-each-loop-php-insert-into-sql-not-inserting-data/21966893?noredirect=1#comment33292440_21950038) about escaping as late as possible. But I'll give you both an upvote anyway, since your answers seem to be essentially correct.

Answer (score 0):

In your foreach loop, run the query. like this:

```
$student_info = array(
        'student_number'=>$student_number,
        'student_first_name'=>$student_first_name,
        'student_middle_name'=>$student_middle_name,
        'student_last_name'=>$student_last_name);

foreach($student_info as $table_row=>$information)
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO student_info_db (`$table_row`) VALUES('".mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $information)."')";
    mysqli_run($connection, $sql);
    echo $table_row . " " . $information;
}
```

More info on [mysqli_query here](https://www.php.net/mysqli_query)

Comment: you are running query for each array element!

Comment: you should have understand since OP new comer in php. and this is not redesign its logic

Comment: -1, embedding unescaped input from `$_POST` into an SQL query is [a bad idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I have now included that.

Comment: Thanks, downvote removed. Although, [as I wrote on Awlad Liton's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21949944/for-each-loop-php-insert-into-sql-not-inserting-data/21949982#comment33292440_21950038), I'd prefer to see the escaping done inside the `foreach`, at the point where the input is actually being turned into SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The [proper way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) to do this is to use a [prepared statement with placeholders](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php):

```
$sql = <<<'END'
    INSERT INTO student_info_db (
        student_number,
        student_first_name,
        student_middle_name,
        student_last_name
    ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
END;

$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare( $sql )

$stmt->bind_param( 's', $_POST['student_number'] );
$stmt->bind_param( 's', $_POST['student_first_name'] );
$stmt->bind_param( 's', $_POST['student_middle_name'] );
$stmt->bind_param( 's', $_POST['student_last_name'] );

$stmt->execute();
```

or, if you insist on using an array as an intermediate stage:

```
$student_info = array(
    'student_number'      => $_POST['student_number'],
    'student_first_name'  => $_POST['student_first_name'],
    'student_middle_name' => $_POST['student_middle_name'],
    'student_last_name'   => $_POST['student_last_name']
);

$keys = array_keys( $student_info );
$columns = implode( ',', $keys );
$holders = implode( ',', array_fill( 0, count($keys), '?' ) );

$sql = "INSERT INTO student_info_db ($columns) VALUES ($holders)";
$stmt = $dbConnection->prepare( $sql )

foreach ( $keys as $key ) {
    $stmt->bind_param( 's', $student_info[$key] );
}
$stmt->execute();
```